# Spring Boot with DB2 HADR ACR config

Tags: spring-boot, db2, db2-luw

Is there a solution that is configured driver properties in the application.properties file?

DB2 HADR using `clientRerouteAlternateServerName, clientRerouteAlternatePortNumber,  enableClientAffinitiesList` to indicate alternate server info.

I tried use below code to config datasource.

```

```
@Bean
public DataSource initds(){
    Properties p = new Properties();
    p.setProperty("user", "user");
    p.setProperty("password", "password");
    p.setProperty("clientRerouteAlternateServerName", "172.30.1.60,172.30.1.61");
    p.setProperty("clientRerouteAlternatePortNumber", "53000,53000");
    p.setProperty("enableClientAffinitiesList", "1");

    DriverManagerDataSource dmds  = new DriverManagerDataSource();
    dmds.setDriverClassName("com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver");
    dmds.setConnectionProperties(p);
    dmds.setUrl("jdbc:db2://172.30.1.60:53000/dbsam");

    return dmds;
}
```

```

Comment: Clarify the question, are you saying that *reroute is not happening* with your configuration?  Give details.

Comment: No, routing is not a problem. But I want to put the configuration information (driver properties) in the spring application.properties file instead of  Hard coding.